# How to hide div 15 seconds after toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a music player that is toggled off on page load. To show the player users must click a button. How can i make the player disappear after it is toggled to show and in the event of a mouse hover over the player, keep the player showing?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scplay").hide();
    

    $(".musicbutton").click(function(){
        $(".scplay").fadeToggle();
    });

        
    $(".scplay").hover(function(){
        $(".scplay").show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="musicbutton">musicbutton</button>
<div class="scplay">scplay</div>
```

Comment: try with setTimeout();

Comment: Calling `show()` on `hover` is redundant as the element already has to be visible to be hovered in the first place

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout()` method:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var element = $(".scplay");
  element.hide();
  $(".musicbutton").click(function() {
    element.fadeToggle(3000, function() {
      setTimeout(function() {
        //your code here
        element.css('color', '#F00');
      }, 15000)

    });
  });
  //this does not make sense
  element.hover(function() {
    element.show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="musicbutton">musicbutton</button>
<div class="scplay">scplay</div>
```

Using *hover* on a **hidden** element does not make sense, the element itself has to be **visible** to use *hover* on it. If you need any further help just say the word.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".musicbutton").click(function(){
        setTimeout(function(){$(".scplay").fadeToggle();},15000);

    });
```

This will do the work for you.
It will execute `$(".scplay").fadeToggle();` code after 15000ms

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure what you want to achive but with fadeToggle() you have not much control.

Wo what you can do is split function on two separate fadeIn and fadeOut

```js
$(".musicbutton").click(function(){
   if($(this).hasClass("active")){ //when button is clicked OFF
      $(".message").empty().text("you just unclicked button - wait 1,5 second");
      setTimeout(function(){
          $(".scplay").fadeOut();
          $(".message").empty().text("button is un-clicked, cool!");
      }, 1500);
      $(this).removeClass("active");
   }  else {//when is clicked
      $(".scplay").fadeIn();
      $(".message").empty().text("button is clicked");
      $(this).addClass("active");
   }   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="musicbutton">My button</div>

<div class="message"></div>
```

Going further you can do callback on fadeOut() or fadeIn() functions

```
$(".scplay").fadeOut(400, function(){  
do whatever you want after animation complete
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass function into the FadeToggle that will occures on the end of the toggle so you need to pass a function with setTimeout that will make the fadeOut again

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $scplay = $(".scplay"); // to avoid extra calling of jquery function
    $scplay.hide();
    

    $(".musicbutton").click(function(){
        $scplay.fadeToggle(function() {
             setTimeout(function(){ $(".scplay").fadeOut(); }, 15000);
        });
    });

        
    $scplay.hover(function(){
        $scplay.show();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="musicbutton">musicbutton</button>
<div class="scplay">scplay</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="scplay" ng-if="showTrue">scplay</div>
$scope.showTrue==true;
$scope.login $timeout(function () { $scope.showTrue = false; }, 15000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
you can use setTimeout function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".scplay").hide();    

   $(".musicbutton").click(function(){
      $(".scplay").fadeToggle();
   });

  $(".scplay").hover(function(){
    $(".scplay").show();
    setTimeout(function () { $('.scplay').fadeOut('fast'); }, 15000);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a callback function every time you use jQuery show() or toggle() functions.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".scplay").hide();
    
    function callback(){
        clearTimeout(t);
        window.t = setTimeout(function() {
            $(".scplay").hide();
        }, 15000);
    }

    $(".musicbutton").click(function(){
        $(".scplay").fadeToggle(callback);
    });

        
    $(".scplay").hover(function(){
        $(".scplay").show(callback);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="musicbutton">musicbutton</button>
<div class="scplay">scplay</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling hover on a hidden element is not possible you can put `.scplay` class inside a div and call hover event on that div
here is a jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kdr7pL1s/

Answer (score 0):

- Use setTimeout () to hide .scplay when not hover.
- Control setTimeout using a boolean(bPlayerStatus).
- Here, setTimeout is in a separate function called setTime().
- So, when "hover" event occured t(setTimeout) will be cleared.
- When .musicbutton "click" or .scplay "mouseleave" occured t will be set to setTimeout (togglePlayer, 15000)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var bPlayerStatus = false,
      scplay = $(".scplay"),
      t;

  scplay.hide();

  function togglePlayer () {
    scplay.fadeToggle();
  }
  function setTime () {
    clearTimeout (t); 
    if (!bPlayerStatus) {
      t = setTimeout (togglePlayer, 5000);
    }
  }

  $(".musicbutton").click(function(){
    bPlayerStatus = false;
    togglePlayer ();
    setTime ();
  });

  scplay.hover(function(){
    if (!bPlayerStatus) {
      bPlayerStatus = true;
      setTime ();
    }
  });   
  $(scplay).mouseleave(function(){
    bPlayerStatus = false;
    setTime ();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="musicbutton">musicbutton</button>
<div class="scplay">scplay</div>
```